# Parsing large text area - difficulty extracting info - Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am writing a program that will deal with formatting the text in a text area.

The user will use Ctrl + A, Ctrl + C to copy the entirety of a web page, then paste that text into a text area. The program will take the text area, remove the junk, and output the important information to then be copied and pasted into a different system.

The concept is simple, but based on my education in programming I need a little help with the pseudocode to make sure I write this correctly and efficiently. I know this website is about code review and refactoring, so I've waited to post until I had some code written. I have already spent about three weeks on this project and I am moving too slowly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I know (or think I know) needs to be done:
 - The program will use a loop to pass through the text box contents **one time**, extracting the important information and putting it into the appropriate variables
 - There will be a two dimensional array, or rather, an array of objects. The objects will be the account lines, each with information like account number, device type, phone number, etc.
 - The system needs to be able to identify certain fields that can be blank. I will give an example:

Text that will be in the text box:

Account Number - Account Name - Product - Phone - Extension - Equipment - Status - Start Date - Order ID

ER4402 - testaccount - Unlimited Product - 1234567890 - 987 - FRZ142 - Active - 12-12-12 - ABC12345
ER4403 - testaccount2 - Unlimited Product -  -  -  - Active - 12-12-12 - ABC12345

Notice the second has empty fields. I think they would be /t in the text box.

Edit: I pressed enter too soon... writing more info now

Here are the objects I've made

```
// Customer "class"
var customer = {
    name: "",
    phone: "",
    compName: "",
    email: "",
    getInfo: function () {
        return "Details: " + this.name + ", " + this.phone + ", " + this.compName + ", " + this.email;
    }
}

// Account lines "class"
var account = {
    checked: 0,
    number: "",
    ipbx: "",
    product: "",
    phoneNumb: "",
    ext: "",
    equip: "",
    status: "",
    startDate: "",
    order: "",
    getInfo: function () {
        return "Details: " + this.number + ", " + this.ipbx + ", " + this.product + ", " + this.phoneNumb + ", " + this.ext + ", " + this.equip + ", " + this.status + ", " + this.startDate + ", " + this.order;
    }
}
```

The code:

```
// Parse the input box into an array
var inputArr = document.getElementById("inputBox").value.split(/[ ]/);

var contNameBool = new Boolean();
var compNameBool = new Boolean();
var emailBool = new Boolean();
var accountsBool = new Boolean();
var accountLinesArray = new Array();
var marker = 1;
var arrayNumb = 0;
for(i = 0; i < inputArr.length; i++) {
    switch(inputArr[i]) {
        case "Name":
            if(inputArr[i - 1] == "Summary") {
                contNameBool = true;
                break;
            }
            break;
        case "Details":
            if(contNameBool == true) {
                contNameBool = false;
                break;
            } else if(contNameBool == false && compNameBool == true) {
                compNameBool = false;
                break;
            }
            break;
        case "Customer":
            if(inputArr[i - 1] == "Details") {
                contNameBool = false;
                compNameBool = true;
                break;
            }
            break;
        case "Address":
            if(inputArr[i - 1] == "Profile") {
                compNameBool = false;
                emailBool = true;
                break;
            }
            break;
        case ("VISA" || "MASTERCARD" || "AMERICAN" || "DISCOVER"):
            emailBool = false;
            break;
        case "Show":
            if(inputArr[i + 1] == "next" && inputArr[1 + 2] == "row") {
                accountLinesArray.length = custDet[i - 1];
                break;
            }
            break;
        case "Order":
            if(inputArr[i + 1] == "ID" && inputArr[i + 2] == "MRC") {
                accountsBool = true;
                break;
            }
            break;
    }

    if(contNameBool == true && inputArr[i] != "Name") {
        if(inputArr[i].search(",") != -1) {
            var temp = inputArr[i].split(/[,]/);
            temp.reverse();
            if(customer.name == "") {
                customer.name = temp.join(" ");
            } else {
                customer.name = customer.name + " " + temp.join(" ");
            }
        } else {
            if(customer.name == "") {
                customer.name = inputArr[i];
            } else {
                customer.name = customer.name + " " + inputArr[i];
            }
        }
    } else if(compNameBool == true) {
        if (customer.compName == "") {
            customer.compName = inputArr[i + 1] + " ";
        } else if(inputArr[i + 1] == "Details") {
            void(0);
        } else {
            customer.compName = customer.compName + inputArr[i + 1] + " ";
        }
    } else if(emailBool == true) {
        if(customer.email == "") {
            customer.email = inputArr[i + 1];
        } else if(inputArr[i + 1] == "VISA" || "MASTERCARD" || "AMERICAN" || "DISCOVER") {
            void(0);
        } else {
            customer.email = customer.email + " " + inputArr[i + 1];

        }
    } else if(accountsBool == true) {
        if(inputArr[i].replace(/[\t]/))
        switch(marker) {
            case 1:
                accountLinesArray[arrayNumb] = new account;
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
            case 7:
                break;
            case 8:
                break;
            case 9:
                break;
        }
        if (marker == 9) {
            marker = 1;
        } else {
            marker++;
        }
    }
}

/*

customer.name = prompt("Error: Could not locate a valid Contact Name. Please input Contact Name.");
customer.compName = prompt("Error: Could not locate a valid Company Name. Please input Company Name.");
customer.email = prompt("Error: Could not locate a valid Email Address. Please input Email Address.");

*/

document.getElementById("contactNameOutput").innerHTML = customer.name;
// document.getElementById("contactNameOutput").innerHTML = inputArr;
document.getElementById("companyNameOutput").innerHTML = customer.compName;
document.getElementById("emailAddressOutput").innerHTML = customer.email;
```

}

The problem I'm having is figuring out how to get the program to identify when one account line has ended and a new one has begun.

I've made a marker to have the program go back to the first part of the array, but I can't wrap my head around how to get it to identify if a field is blank and how to move on to the next field and reach the end of the account line in the right order.

I realize I just asked a lot, but I don't know where to go or how to proceed with this. I admit that it's a bit over my head, but due to my frustration and level of completion, I really thought I should post it before I put the project on a hiatus. Any feedback or help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, but Code Review is for improving code that works, not how to fix program so that it works. For more information, see the [FAQ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this a lot in php with [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-match-all.php). But this should also work in [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520611/how-can-i-match-multiple-occurrences-with-a-regex-in-javascript-similar-to-phps).

My first blind guess for a regular expression: (Having some real samples would make this easier ..., furthermore I assume that the dashes are only for the layout and not in the data, and I wrap every part for readability .)

```
/([A-Z]{2}\d{4})\s*
([a-z0-9]+)\s*
(.*?)\s*
(\d+)?\s*
(\d{3})?\s*
([A-Z]{3}\d{3})?\s*
(Active|foo|bar)\s*
(\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)\s*
([A-Z]{3}\d{5})/
```

If you are not familiar with regular expression:

- `\s*` is any white space
- `\d` are numbers
- `{2}` is an exact count of 2,
- `+` is one or more characters
- `-` is none or more characters
- `)?` is optional
- `?)` is a lower greedyness

For more details see: [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html)

Comment: Thank you. I will read more on regular expressions. I will post again when I have code that works.

Comment: @Mrow Upvote and except the answer before the topic get closed :P

Comment: I can't upvote. But I will accept the asnwer. Thank you. :)